# Some users can debug my page some users get Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am having problem's posting in facebook links from my webpage. When ever I try to post a link from my website in my facebook page, It only displays the link without the text or the image or the title that are entered in the meta og tags. When ever I had this type of problem, I went in the debugger tool and debugged the page that I am willing to post. Then facebook was reading the link with no problem at all.

Unfortunately Two weeks have past since the debugger tool stopped working for me returning “Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped” when ever I tried to debug a link from my website. I tried to solve the problem by removing og tags or even changing them with no results or even flushing my dns settings. I checked my server settings with my provider but with no success. By the way my providers facebook account could debug the page with 200 response code but for me, I still got “Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.”.

I even used the following link to test what facebook is scrapping 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=pygmaxia.gr but I got 
“Document returned no data as a response.“

I reported the issue to several help agencies like stack overflow and facebook support page or other forums, but the response I got back was “Debugger works for me with your link”.

A friend of mine reported that he can also debug the links with no problem at all. Others report “Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.”.. I really can't understand what is going on, for some users debugger works with my page and for some does not. I am suspecting that facebook debugger is caching on user account level.

I decided to create a new account and test the page with the debugger again since debugger is only used by registered users.

**And I got the following result. My new user can debug the page but my old user can't!**

[image]

With the new user I am able to debug all my links with no problem at all. This leads me to the conclusion that some accounts are locked or cached by facebook and some are not.

I logged in facebook with two different browsers, one with my old account and one with my new account. Finally I got the result In front of my eyes.

Anyone had similar problems and had a solution?

Thank you

> **Update**: I talked with facebook support but they can't find out what is going
>   on. One thing I did to work around the problem was to create a new
>   facebook account and tried to debug the page again. It worked!. So
>   it seems that facebook is actually caching at user level. But still my
>   account can't debug my page.
>
> **Update 2**: I found a great consulting website that really helped and pointed out the problem. You can find the solution here http://www.itoctopus.com/problems-with-sharing-links-of-a-joomla-website-on-facebook/comment-page-1#comment-14288

My problem was that facebook has a problem with gzip compression. Look more details here

https://www.facebook.com/csharpsdk/posts/165605793549074

If you are using joomla there is a quick fix plugin can be found here https://github.com/dgt41/facebookfix .

In general, your website will support gzip for everyone, but not for facebook bots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a great consulting website that really helped and pointed out the problem. You can find the solution here http://www.itoctopus.com/problems-with-sharing-links-of-a-joomla-website-on-facebook/comment-page-1#comment-14288

My problem was that facebook has a problem with **gzip compression**. Look for more details here

https://www.facebook.com/csharpsdk/posts/165605793549074

If you are using joomla there is a quick fix plugin that can be found here https://github.com/dgt41/facebookfix .

In general, your website will support gzip for everyone, but not for facebook bots.

anyway this fixed my  **Error parsing input URL, no data was found**

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fpygmaxia.gr 
works fine for me. Did you use this tool? Facebook use cache to store information about your website.

Comment: hmm it gives me Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped. again even when i click your url wtf?

Comment: chrome worked..But firefox is not even if I clear it's cache. then it switches and firefox works and chrome does not, or sometimes both work and sometimes both don't. it seams that browser is caching or there is some kind of loadbalancing going on. I also found that an issue would be my webserver firewall settings that is probably blocking facebook. I am talking with the administrator at the moment, I will update as soon I have news. thank you for you info

Comment: The article I found about the firewall http://www.gearhack.com/Forums/DisplayComments.php?file=Computer/Network/Internet/Preventing_Your_Web_Server_From_Blocking_Facebook_Share

Comment: Can't solve the problem. I am still getting Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped. Is there a way to debug the error and see why is facebook having trouble scrapping the link?

Comment: I also have this exact issue - several users cannot share and cannot debug, while for other users it's ok. It's really frustrating, have you found a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

**You guys may be blocking your Referer.**

I experienced the same issue with Firefox but when I allowed my Referer to be sent it works.

Facebook probably doesn't want external websites to make requests, especially since these requests could be done in AJAX for a bad purpose. But they make a mistake by not allowing empty referers.